# How to write unit tests to this specific ActiveRecord class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec

I'd like to write unit tests in `Rspec` to the class:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cart_items
  has_many :carts, through: :cart_items

  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

I'm not sure what I should test here ... Can you give some tips about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem, you can do this

```
describe Item do
  it {should validate_presence_of :price}
  it {should validate_presence_of :name}
  it {should have_many(:cart_items)}
  it {should have_many(:carts).through(:cart_items)}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `spec/models/item_spec.rb` u can write your Unit Test.

i am just giving you an example what you should write in your spec for this particular Model

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Task do
   before do
      @task = Task.new(name: "Example1", price:123)
   end 
   subject { @task }

   it { should respond_to(:name) } 
   it { should respond_to(:price) }  
   it { should respond_to(:cart_items) }   
   it { should be_valid }

   describe "when name is not present" do
      before { @task.name = " " }
         it { should_not be_valid } 
   end 
end
```

you can write more according to validation,requirements,fields,associations etc